# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions; what's the proper way to set up this transition?

Tags: swift

I have an onboarding flow that I want to present to a new user before letting them into the app. I want to specifically use `present()` to do this so that I can nicely `dismiss()` the onboarding flow. This code is working, but I *am* getting the unbalanced transition warning on the TabBarController. Is there a better way to do this?

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
        Core.shared.setIsNewUser()
        
        if Core.shared.isNewUser() {
         
            let tabBarCon = TabBarController() // this is the root of the main app
            let welcomeViewCon = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: OBPage0()) // This is my onboarding flow
            window?.rootViewController = tabBarCon
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            welcomeViewCon.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            tabBarCon.present(welcomeViewCon, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
```

Note: I know that there are many questions with a similar title, I have reviewed them and still not found an answer to this problem.

Comment: Can you try to set `animated: false` if it isn't what you want, you can try to move this logic when `tabBarCon` fully loaded, for example in `viewDidLoad()`. It looks like, you trying to present `welcomeViewCon` from `tabBarCon` but it's not fully displayed (appear) on the screen, so that's why you get a warning.